# C# SpecFlow: What's the right way to use both unit tests and UI tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bdd, specflow

I'm implementing tests written in Gherkin using SpecFlow. The tests are very high level, for example:

```
Given Youtube's watch Page
When I click play
Then I see an ad
```

which can be implemented into a UI test or a unit test.

The end result is that in the same project I have a mix of UI tests and unit tests. This creates a problem when running the project, due to the UI tests being very slow compared to unit tests.

My question is, how should specification by example be implemented in the UI tests VS Unit tests context?

Answer (score 2):

You should always have this kind of tests in its own project and they are strictly integration tests. This gives you option to run real unit tests all the time and run these tests frequently but not every time. And these tests are by definition integration tests, i.e. going through multiple layers without mocking.

It does not mean for every single scenario you need to go through a browser (or a headless browser) though.